# In Book Of Genesis Chapter 6 Paragraph 2 is it referring to rape?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, sexuality, parashat-bereishit

[Genesis 6:2](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8171#showrashi=true):

> בוַיִּרְאוּ בְנֵי הָאֱלֹהִים אֶת בְּנוֹת הָאָדָם כִּי טֹבֹת הֵנָּה
>   וַיִּקְחוּ לָהֶם נָשִׁים מִכֹּל אֲשֶׁר בָּחָרוּ:
>
> That the sons of the nobles saw the daughters of man when they were
>   beautifying themselves, and they took for themselves wives from
>   whomever they chose.
>
> גוַיֹּאמֶר יְהֹוָה לֹא יָדוֹן רוּחִי בָאָדָם לְעֹלָם בְּשַׁגָּם הוּא
>   בָשָׂר וְהָיוּ יָמָיו מֵאָה וְעֶשְׂרִים שָׁנָה:
>
> 3And the Lord said, "Let My spirit not quarrel forever concerning man,
>   because he is also flesh, and his days shall be a hundred and twenty
>   years."

It seems like this was the 2nd sin of many more to come, but what does it mean?
Does it mean that the nobles would take woman against their will (rape) regardless of if she's married or not?

also it translates the word "טֹבֹת" as "beautifying"  and not "good"
this is puzzling.
also, it seems like to me that this might have been rape, since rape is also considered like stealing, and it goes on further in the next paragraph to say that all flesh on the earth has become corrupt. and then it goes on to talk about robbery.
I'm still not understanding fully of what exactly went on anybody care to clarify?

Comment: Whose translation is that? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: That translation looks like the Judaica Press version. Rashi there writes: " Heb., טֹבֹת. Said Rabbi Judan: It is written טבת [i.e., instead of טובות. Thus it can be read טָבַת, meaning to beautify.] When they would beautify her, adorned to enter the nuptial canopy, a noble would enter and have relations with her first (Gen. Rabbah 26:5)." and then " Even a married woman, even males and animals (Gen. Rabbah ad loc.)."

Comment: @Danno and the Rashi is the answer "a noble would enter and have relations with her first". = rape. Feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: How are you getting rape from that?  It could have been consensual for all we know from this passage.

Comment: @MonicaCellio It describes Droit du seignor which gave the noble the "right of the first night" which the Greeks and Romans as well as the French nobility before the revolution. Also like Pharoah and Avimelech in Genesis or Achashveros and Esther.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rav Hirsch translates טבת as *fair* טבת מראה and points out that the usual idiom of לקח אשה means marriage and that the nobles, the children of the line of Seth, took wives without considering where they came from, who their families were, and what was their character. As a result, the women influenced the children who then became more and more depraved. Eventually they came to believe that they were entitled to whatever and whomever they wanted to take, which is the basic concept of *robbery*.

> It always a question which tendency will prevail in the children, and
>   whether the longer the admixture continues the more the depravity will
>   grow. The following verse gives the disclosure how the problem settled
>   itself here.

Then they eventually got to the point that [Rashi](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8171#v=2&showrashi=true) makes.

> **when they were beautifying themselves**: Heb., טֹבֹת. Said Rabbi Judan:
>   It is written טבת [i.e., instead of טובות. Thus it can be read טָבַת,
>   meaning to beautify.] When they would beautify her, adorned to enter
>   the nuptial canopy, a noble would enter and have relations with her
>   first (Gen. Rabbah 26:5).
>
> **from whomever they chose**: Even a married woman, even males and animals (Gen. Rabbah ad loc.).